ADF Copy data activity pagination with continuation token with GET request
I am building ETL pipeline in ADF service to load data from API, but I am having difficulties implementing pagination rules with continuation token.
I know that, according to Azure documentation, it should be possible to use this approach - next request’s header = property value in current response body.
The structure I would like to achieve:

make a GET request to https://test.net/abc/tableName?size=1000 using pipeline Web activity, and get a continuationToken from response body as an output

store it in Set Variable activity

use Copy activity to make a GET request to
https://test.net/abc/tableName?size=1000&seekOperation=Next with
header = continuationToken from response body of Web activity (stored in variable). Make another GET requests to retrieve all data until continuationToken is non-existent in response body, each time adding token to header.


I am trying pagination rules, so I set something like this, but it is not working:
    "paginationRules": {
        "supportRFC5988": "true",
        "Headers.ContinuationToken": {
            "value": "$.continuationToken",
            "type": "Expression"
        },
        "EndCondition:body.continuationToken": "NonExist"
}

Error I am getting is something like this:

Failure happened on 'Source' side.
ErrorCode=RestInvalidPaginationRule,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Invalid
PaginationRule, RuleKey='body.continuationToken',
RuleValue='NonExist',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

Also, I don't know how to make it do GET request first time in copy activity, using value stored in variable, and then retrieve it from response body of this request.
In additional headers I added Token: @variables('continuationToken'), but how to make it work iteratively?
I would be really grateful if someone can help me with constructing this logic.
As for now, it looks like this:


Is your REST API contains the next page URL in the header or in the Body of the current page response? Can you explain with a sample JSON response of current page and next page?

The link for the second request is always the same - https://test.net/abc/tableName?size=1000&seekOperation=Next, what is changed - only continuation token in response body that I need to put to headers each new request to get another batch of 1000

The response is something like this:
{
"continuationToken": "abcde",
"totalCount": 999,
"items": [......

Is continuationToken means the authorization token?

This is a string token returned for queries that can be used if there are more results to be read than the maximum count of items an action can return.


Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=RestInvalidPaginationRule,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Invalid PaginationRule, RuleKey='body.continuationToken', RuleValue='NonExist',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

The error you are facing is because you are not passing correct value to end condition parameter it should look like below as you are accessing the body node as End condition:
"EndCondition:$.continuationToken": "NonExist"

For your requirement you can try this approach with until loop and some variables to store the value for next iteration.

for above image you need to follow below steps:

First take copy activity to copy the data of first iteration where in continuation token value is not require in header.
Then take web activity to get the  continuation token  value for first iteration.
Then take the Set variable to store the value you got from previous web activity.
Then take until activity with below activities and condition as value of next value variable as null.



First Set variable (initial value) activity will store the value you got from variable outside of until activity (first value).
web activity to get the  continuation token  value for every iteration.
Copy activity to use that value and copy the data.
Second set variable(next value) to store the  continuation token  value got from web activity.
Third set variable(switch value) to swap the values of First Set variable(inital value) with second set variable(next value).

This is sample logic you can develop in ADF for your requirement
